# weird blurring of tiles in unity2d tilemap

Tags: unity, sprites

My tiles don't have any anti-aliasing because I am going for a pixelated look. But when I add my tiles to a tile map it automatically puts anti-aliasing on them. My tiles look like this:
[image]
when they should look like this:
[image]
Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: We'll need a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example. Edit your question to walk us through every step we need to follow to reproduce this problem in a new, empty project - including the settings on your tilemap, and import settings for your sprite images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you need to change your texture import settings 'Filter Mode' to 'Point':
[image: Change Filter mode to Point and apply.]

Comment: the compression should be changed too (to none, if I remember correctly)